# Angular swaps out ng-include with binding data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an issue that I've never seen so far where Angular changes what was an standard ng-include DOM section of a directive with actual json data from a binding.

The symptoms are the entire directive template in three directives on the page are swapped out from the view html with the same set of json data.  The list is a set of data in another controller on the page.  When I look at the source on the page I literally see the template completely gone and json instead.

The change that seems to spawn this is working with a list that's being bound in another part of the page.  I was initially trying to remove data from the list as a result of a delete call to the web server.  The call comes back fine, the list is changed inside of my code and then, wham, the templates are swapped out by angular.  Ironically the table that displays the list still works fine!

I've used this pattern with success numerous times in other parts of my app so I'm at a lose at the moment to explain it.  The only big change I've done is inject the $rootScope in some of my factories (that maintain state) so that they could fire messages to other directives and controllers.

So I understand it's tough to nail the exact problem from what I've given but what I'm hoping for is some helpful advice in tracking it down.  I don't know if it's worth figuring out how to put a watch on the template change but I also figured there has to be a pretty unusual case where angular swaps out html for raw data.

Thanks!

Comment: Hard to help you without any code to look at.  A plunker or jsfiddle would be nice.

Comment: I totally get that but unfortunately its part of a pretty large page with several moving parts that don't make it a great jsfiddle.  I haven't tried to reproduce the problem on a smaller scale but I'm doing to the exact same thing on other pages just fine.  I'm looking for thoughts on what might cause Angular to swap out DOM nodes for json data.  That whole thing seems pretty peculiar.